# XML data visualization

Tags: xml

What type of structure would I need to create charts like the following?

http://www.axiis.org/examples.html

If you could provide me with a link to an xml file which shows the type of structure that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the framework/visualization engine you use to create the graphs.

The data is probably represented as a set of series that have entries that consists of categories and labels.

The XML-data used in Axiis examples can be found their [Google Code repository](http://code.google.com/p/axiis/source/browse/#svn/trunk/examples/src/data)

Comment: Great Thanks , So would you say if I used there exciting code and created my xml-data with the necessarly structure it would work ?

Comment: Sure, why not. If that is what they propose their software does.

Comment: Is that typcially how you could use a engine ? I am a php developer so everything I create is by scratch so im unknown on the use of engines like this

Comment: Typical way for using engines/framework is that 1) You think what you want to achive 2) Select a framework that does what you want to achieve 3) Study the framework to know how you can achive your goal using it i.e. find out how to use the interfaces of the frame 4) Hope that the framework works. 

In this case you would go around creating an XML-representation of your data in the axiis-format and find a way how to visualize it with Axiis. 

By the way: even PHP developer can use frameworks instead of doing things from scratch. :)

Answer (score 2):

XML is just a way to store data. What you need is a visualization engine that can interpret your data.

With regard to "what structure": Totally depends on what you want to visualize. I think you're starting at the wrong end.

Comment: So if I wanted to start at the right end and try and work with this type of thing what would be the best way be ?

Comment: Find out what data you have. Find the guy or users who needs the visualizations if it's not yourself. Ask yourself or those people what they want to communicate. Think about a way to communicate this with a diagram type. Find a diagram library that creates such diagrams. Find out if it fits your needs. Find out what format you need to format the data. Test if it works. Write a converter for your data. Visualize.

Comment: "Write a converter for your data" Does this mind converting say a form value into xml which get's visulized

Answer (score 1):

You could to click `Source` below your desired sample and to browse for `data` folder on the left frame. There are many xml samples in there, like [2008_Olympics_Large.xml](http://www.axiis.org/examples/srcview/source/data/2008_Olympics_Large.xml.txt)